# jQuery textchanged bind occurs on irrelevant keypresses

Tags: php, jquery, api, text

Here's the code I have:

```
var tourl;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#url").bind("textchange",showPage);
    $("input#url").bind("textchange",toggleButtons);
    $("input#url").focus();


    $("form#surlform").submit(function(){
        var url = $("input#url").val(); 
        $.get("api/create.php?a=&url=" + url, function(data) {
                $("input#url").val(data);
                $("input#url").select();
                $('#button').hide();
                $('#hbutton').show();
                tourl = data;
                $('#hbutton').bind('click', function() {
                    window.location = tourl + "-";
                });
            });

        return false;
    });
    });

$(document).click(function(){
    showPage();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(){
    showPage();
});
function toggleButtons() {
    $('#hbutton').hide();
    $('#button').show();
}
```

As you can see, data is entered into the form, jQuery stops normal form submission and instead contacts an API. On response from the API, it changes the text box text to the response and highlights it. It then changes the submit button to be a button that links to the output from the API (it's a URL). I am using a bind to the textchange event to then change the button back when the text in the form field is changed.

However, instead of triggering when the text in the field is actually changed, it seems to be on any keypress. For example, if I wanted to copy the output, I'd use Ctrl+C to do so, however when I do this, it counts it as the text being changed and changes the button back.

Is there any way I could make this *only* trigger when the text in the box is actually changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't You use the event `change` instead of `textchange`? By using `change` the textbox has to lost focus prior to the `change` event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `textchange` event I would use `change` event (and don't understand why using `bind`...):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#url").change(function(){
        showPage();
        toggleButtons();
    });
    $("input#url").focus();
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, but when the form is used, because the API result is highlighted there, users would simply just start typing or paste something in. They wouldn't focus off the text box until they actually clicked the button, so it would need to have changed back before that. I'd really like it to just trigger when there's a change in the data in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Save last text into a var and compare with the actual text, like the following:

```
var lastText = jQuery('parentElement element').val();
jQuery('parentElement').on('keyup', 'element', function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() !== lastText) {
        // do what do you want
    }

    lastText = jQuery(this).val();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fMWh/3/)**

Comment: Good concept, but Ctrl + C still triggers it - weird as it's not changing the text in any way, but I've tried both your demo and my page with your code, and both wrongly trigger on Ctrl + C.

Comment: @HenryCole It's not triggering on ctrl + c, the problem was the default value, check the updated demo now and you'll see.

Comment: But that's without anything in.. have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2fMWh/1/ - if you highlight the text and press Ctrl + C, the alert pops up. The same goes for my implementation, where the text is highlighted automatically using jQuery. All I do is press Ctrl + C and it triggers.

Comment: @HenryCole It's happens just on first time because the lastText initial value is '' and the textarea initial value is 'sample', so you have to change lastText initial value too. http://jsfiddle.net/2fMWh/3/